# Spring integration SocketException:Connection reset

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-websocket

My server code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41765722/3871754

My client code: https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/simple-java-socket-client-class-program

When I run the client, I get on server logs: `o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection : Read exception 127.0.0.1 SocketException:Connection reset`

When I tested it with the tool: https://sourceforge.net/projects/sockettest/ then server works properly with sockettest app, I think this is a client issue.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory` uses `ByteArrayCrLfSerializer` to deserialize client requests:

```
/**
 * Reads data in an InputStream to a byte[]; data must be terminated by \r\n
 * (not included in resulting byte[]).
 * Writes a byte[] to an OutputStream and adds \r\n.
 *
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @since 2.0
 */
public class ByteArrayCrLfSerializer extends AbstractPooledBufferByteArraySerializer {
```

You should be sure that your client really sends messages terminated with the `\r\n`. According to the sample it's not:

```
writeToAndReadFromSocket(socket, "GET /\n\n");
```

Comment: How to change serializer on server? I want to use ByteArrayStxEtxSerializer

Comment: `AbstractConnectionFactory.setDeserializer()`

Comment: In my case it was TcpNetServerConnectionFactory